# Ansible Special Characters in passwords

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-2.x

I read my root passwords from an encrypted ansible-vault file. 
But when I use it on ansible_become_pass the operation fails because the password contains a special character. In my example "**#**"

This is my yml:

```
- hosts: sirius
  remote_user: ansusr
  become: yes
  vars_files:
     - vault_vars.yml
  become_pass: "{{ root_pass_sirius }}"
```

`ansible-playbook check.yml --ask-vault-pass`

`fatal: FAILED! => {"msg": "{{ TesT#1234 }}: template error while templating string: unexpected char '#' at 6. String: {{ TesT#1234 }}"}`

How to mask the `#` Char?

Comment: this sounds similar: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/25559

Answer (score 1):

Use `set +H` before actually running that encryption command.

Comment: Ansible-vault has no such key.

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
become_pass: "{{ root_pass_sirius | regex_escape() }}"
```

Comment: sorry, but no. Same Error message as before

Answer (score 0):

Try single quotes instead of double:

```
become_pass: '{{ root_pass_sirius }}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that you can try is the quote filter:

```
become_pass: "{{ root_pass_sirius | quote }}"
```

Comment: Nope, no effect

Answer (score 0):

Try this `"'"{{  }}"'"`

or  this `$'{{ }}'`

Its Jinja templates

Answer (score 0):

I had a different symbol: $ and when decrypting this symbol disappeared (along with what came after it) and the following solution helped:

1. replace " with '

That is:

shell: 'echo '{{ password }}'' - this works correctly, but here:

shell: 'echo '{{ password }}'' - it doesn't work.

2. add replace

That is:

```
- name: replace
  set_fact:
    password: "{{ password | replace ('\n', '') | replace ('\r', '') }}"
```

In sum, it looks like this:

```
- name: replace
  set_fact:
    password: "{{ password | replace ('\n', '') | replace ('\r', '') }}"
- name: echo
  shell: "echo '{{ password }}'"
```