# How to handle special character in ansible_ssh_pass variable of ansible inventory file?

Tags: ansible, special-characters, ansible-inventory

The ! character in ansible_ssh_pass is causing error

#command

```
ansible -m ping target1 -i ConfigFiles/hosts.txt
```

#error

```
ansible 2.6.20
target1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

#inventory file

```
target1 ansible_host=0.0.0.0 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_ssh_user=xyz ansible_ssh_pass=abc@xyz@2020!
```

I have tried suggestion mentioned on below post but didn't worked.
[Ansible Special Characters in passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153403/ansible-special-characters-in-passwords)

Also while searching solution i came across

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html

```
{% raw %} ... {% endraw %}

!unsafe tag
```

But while using those tag i came across template error.

I am aware of the fact to use key based authentication or using vault.

But currently i am looking if we have solution to use of password in parameter with special characters

Comment: Did you run the ad-hoc command with `-vvv` to make 100% sure the problem is actually the password ?

Comment: Yes i executed.

Answer (score 0):

the solution in the openshift docs worked for me.
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install/configuring_inventory_file.html

for my password of
PW###

### inventory.text

target1 ansible_host=10.10.10.100 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_ssh_user=root ansible_ssh_pass='"PW###"'